# Unity: How to move the camera by a specific amount?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

**Hello!** I am trying to make a dungeon game, sort of like The Binding of Isaac. I am trying to make a script that will move the camera down my a specific amount when the player goes into another room. Right now, I am focusing on the part of the script that will move the camera *down* when the player enters a room from the *top*.

After looking at many other StackOverflow and questions on the Unity site, the line of code I made that moves the camera down enter a room from the top is `Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(0, -10, 0);`. After this line executes, the camera no longer renders anything except for the set background color. I am also concerned about this line of code because I think that it will not move the camera down by 10 points, but will set it to the position `0, -10, 0`, but I'm not sure.

I've also tried getting the individual points from the camera ( `Camera.main.transform.position.x += 10;` for example), but Visual Studio and Unity gives me the error: `Unable to get the return values of position.x because they are not variables`. I have been trying to figure this out for a very long time and can't for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am also concerned about this line of code because I think that it will not move the camera down by 10 points, but will set it to the position 0, -10, 0, but I'm not sure.

Yes, that will indeed set the position to 0, -10, 0, because you are setting the position to a new Vector3 with no reference to the old position.

---

You should instead use `Camera.main.transform.Translate(0, -10, 0)`, which will move the Camera down 10 points on the y-axis **relative** to its current position.

**EDIT:**
The camera will render just the background colour because (I assume) there are no objects in the camera's field of view once its position has been set to (0, -10, 0), therefore only the background is visible.

Comment: Thanks! I'm confused, though. How does the other code make the camera not render anything. Weird. Thanks again, though!

Comment: Because probably at 0, -10, 0 there is no world